# Cannot Resolve Symbol "Default"

Tags: android, utf-8, decode, decoding

I am trying to decode *Text* in Android Studio but it shows me Error on Base64.**DEFAULT**.

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.Decoder(message, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Any Solution for this?

Error in Decoding:
[image: Error in Decoding]

Error Cannot Find Symbol Error Default:
[image: Error Cannot Find Symbol Error Default]

Comment: The Android Base64 class [has a lower-case function called `decode`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode(java.lang.String,%20int)). You're using a library, and it will have a different set of functions. Unless you specify it, or decide to use the embedded ones, there's not really a way to answer this (especially when considering the library likely won't support the same flags as the class that comes with the SDK. You could explicitly use the embedded one with `android.util.Base64.DEFAULT`, but I recommend you look up the docs instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this in following 2 Steps;

**Add this**

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

**Remove these**

```
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Decoder;
```